# Problem with LinearLayout and changing visibility from GONE to VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom LinearLayout that is added to a parent layout. This parent layout can change size, so I'm listening to size change with:

```
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {...}
```

In this method, according to the new size, I hide or show certain members of the LinearLayout with:

```
setVisibility(GONE/VISIBLE);
```

However, the layout doesn't update automatically. The parent layout is resized but the LL is not updated. However, the layout does update after I click a component, which takes me to a different app and come back to the screen.

I've tried forcing a re-draw with:

```
requestLayout();
forceLayout();
invalidate();
```

But this is not working. Any ideas of where I might be getting this wrong?

Edit: code sample

LinearLayout

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    ImageView iv1;
    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(getContext());
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        tv1 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv2 = new TextView(getContext());
        tv3 = new TextView(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);

        iv1 = new ImageView(getContext());
        LayoutParams ivParams = new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, 0);
        ivParams.weight = 1;

        addView(tv1, tvParams);
        addView(iv1, ivParams);
        addView(tv2, tvParams);
        addView(tv3, tvParams);
    }

    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        int heightDp = (int) (h / DENSITY);
        if (heightDp <= 250) {
          tv1.setVisibility(GONE);
          tv2.setVisibility(GONE);
          tv3.setVisibility(GONE);
        } else if (heightDp <= 350) {
          tv1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          tv2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          tv3.setVisibility(GONE);
        } else {
          tv1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          tv2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          tv3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post some sample code of your problem ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf updated :)

Comment: your LinearLayout is in  horizontal orientation ?

Comment: it's vertical, sorry forgot to add that line

Comment: If I use INVISIBLE instead of GONE, it behaves properly, so I suspect the issue has to do with re-layouting the components, which is not being done, Another thing to note is the imageView with adapts it's height via the weight attribute. That might have something to do with the strange behaviour

Comment: `requestLayout()` should be enough. not sure whats going on